# Accidentally created 2 accounts, can they be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-accounts

Is it possible to get the following 2 accounts merged:

https://askubuntu.com/users/11668/chong
https://askubuntu.com/users/4844/tim

Thanks!

Comment: Which account would you like to keep as the "main" account Chong or tim?

Comment: I would like to keep chong please.

Answer (score 2):

Your accounts have been merged - with Chong as the main account.

Comment: I have also two account, i was created the other one b/c i have two  favorite names now i need to merge both of them. could you merge both of them?

Comment: @Achu what are the two accounts?

Comment: Thank you the first one is http://askubuntu.com/users/9701/achu and the second one is http://askubuntu.com/users/11000/ethio  i would like to keep the first one "Achu"   bay the way is it the reputation too?

Comment: @Achu - I've merged your accounts, this includes a merge of your reputation. Both your login OpenIDs will now point to Achu

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question it is not a big dill but my reputation was 263 on Achu and 48 on ethio the sum will be 310 but now 278  why? :)

Comment: @Achu that's because Either account may have provided rep for the other - this technically is not allowed. So if you upvoted any of the questions or answers from one another the system will detect that and factor that in during the merge.